# Change the sequence of ORDER BY in EF Core filtered include

Tags: sql-server, ef-core-5.0

Say I have these entities

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Translation> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class Translation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

And the code below

```
Users
    .Include(u => u.Translations
                    .Where(t => t.Language == "en")
                    .OrderBy(t => t.Name))
    .OrderBy(u => u.Code);
```

will produce this SQL statement

```
...
ORDER BY [u].[Code], [t].[Name]
```

How can I influence the order of the ORDER BY as such?

```
...
ORDER BY [t].[Name], [u].[Code]
```

I have tried

```
Users
    .Include(u => u.Translations
                    .Where(t => t.Language == "en")
                    .OrderBy(t => t.Name)
                    .ThenBy(t => t.User.Code));
```

But the generated SQL statement is more verbose (more joins). Is this the correct way of doing it?

**UPDATE**

The `Include(u => u.Translations.Where(t => t.Language == "en"))` filter will retrieve zero or at most one `Translation` for each `User` so that it could be displayed in a two-dimensional table.

[image]

The column `Code` above belongs to the `User` entity while the column `Name` belongs to the `Translation` entity. The table could be sorted by `Name` first or by `Code` first.

Comment: Why do you want that?  The Include processing tries to keep each User together in the result set.

Comment: I have updated my question to better explain what I'm trying to achieve.